# using db as elasticsearch cache

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, caching

My client came with a requirement where he wants to reduce calls to Elastic Search and wants to save elastic search responses in DB (Key-value) and before querying Elastic Search, he wants to check in DB table. Already have postgresql instance for primary data storage. He doesn't want to use redis or any other service for caching Elastic Search results.

Questions here are:

1. Will this improve search performance?
2. What if we use mongoDB (community version), is it better option than saving data in postgresql?
3. Any other better option for this problem without adding any extra cost to the infra.

Client just wants to improve search, reduce calls to elastic search without adding any extra cost.

Comment: Wow. Typically Elasticsearch (and similar search engines) are used to reduce the load on the relational database.

Comment: If queries are so slow that you don't dare to call ES and want to cache the results I would first start with optimizing your queries before introducing another software component into the mix to hide underlying the problem

Comment: Hello @Val , I just give some opinions. Could you help me to improve the answer? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You need start checking the queries to improve the performance first. I think, you had already done with it. So, at this point, for my opinion, there are different solutions. And also, I need say, my opinions here will be common solutions. I don't know what the problem exactly on your cluster. Just only, I am trying to give some clue for you.

- One of them is, you need to do some scaling operations to handle the requests. For example, you can check the CPU, Ram usage and you can try to increase them.
- The other is, you can rethink about the sharding of the index. Most of time, sharding strategy working to make the queries fast also. Or, You can split the data to multiple index and you can search on the index that have the data you need, etc.
- The other option is, you can use caching in front of the search service. But this is related with your business logic not related with technology or database choice, etc. This should be the last step also.

Elasticsearch is a service that serves the documents near-real time. This is a big opportunity for the business side. You will lose this opportunity with caching the search result. In here, cache TTL is important point as @Val said in comment.

On the other hand, in generally, when you put anything in the stack, you will gain some opportunity but also you will lose some of them.

Comment: Those are all valid points, but again, in my opinion caching should only be considered when all other options have failed, and the OP is probably not there yet. Just throwing in caching in the hope that everything will go better is a lure + caching brings its own load of other issues, the most serious one being how to tune the TTL of the cache and still make sure that the cache is in synch with the underlying data?

Comment: Thank you @Val . Also, I want to say thank you for the all responses of the Elasticsearch tag. You are doing it awesome :)